# On injective holomorphic map into a Hilbert Space.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $G\subset\mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a domain and let $f$ be an **injective** holomorphic map from $G$ into a complex Banach space $H$ (you may restrict to Hilbert Spaces only).

Q: Is $f$ necessarily a homeomorphism?

Thank you.

Comment: No, unless $dim(H)=n$. Do you know examples of smooth injective maps which are not homeomorphisms to their images? Holomorphic examples are similar.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Sorry, my intuition usually fails when trying to construct counterexamples in the holomorphic category. Could you please hint one? After that I'll just add that $f$ is a homeomorphism by default (I'm mostly interested in the second part).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start with the algebraic set $A=\{(x,y)\in {\mathbb C}^2: xy=0\}$. Can you express it as the image of the surface 
$$
S=\{(x,0): x\in {\mathbb C}\} \cup \{(x,1): x\in {\mathbb C}, x\ne 0\}
$$
under and injective holomorphic map $F$? If you can, can you also make $S$ smaller so that the smaller surface $S'$ admits a biholomorphic embedding into ${\mathbb C}$  and $F(S)$ is still not a topological manifold?

One can make examples where the domain of your holomorphic map is connected. For this, the image will be contained in, say, a nodal elliptic curve in ${\mathbb C}^2$.

Comment: Sorry again, but I don't get the last part; maybe I should have specified that the notion of domain included connectedness.

Comment: Did you get the first part? For the 2nd part: Do you know what a nodal curve is? (A nodal curve is smooth except for one point where it locally looks like my first example.)